# How to use "matches": ["https://www.SAMPLE_TEXT.com/*"] for every website?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make an chrome extension that detects what site you are on, and it blocks you from entering unless its a site that's allowed by the program, and if it isn't allowed it redirects you to an allowed site

im trying to use this code, to redirect to another webiste:

```
if (document.URL.includes("https://www.facebook.com") ) {
    //something
} else {
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

and it doesn't work, even though this code works:

```
if (document.URL.includes("https://www.facebook.com")) {
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

i assume it works because i have this in my manifest.json:

```
"matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"]
```

So how can you use matches with every website?

thanks for the help!

Comment: `"matches": ["http://*/*"]` in manifest

Comment: Switch to a [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-RuleAction), which is faster and offers smoother user experience.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal thanks! it works